# OrCAD: Determining which trace in Secondary Sweep is which after simulating

Tags: simulation, orcad

When you run a primary and secondary sweep, there are multiple sets of traces for the same signal, where each individual trace represents a different value from the secondary sweep. In OrCAD 16.0, I want to know which secondary sweep value produced a particular trace; how do I do that?

Edit: I tried Linkyyy's suggestion and got the following info box:

[image: Info box from a single trace.]

So it tells me what generated that trace, but not the specific value of the secondary parameter that generated it.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I be using parametric sweeps instead of and/or in addition to secondary sweeps?

Comment: If it’s like microcap, you hover the mouse over a trace and it gives you a reference number.

Comment: Apparently it's not, because it doesn't, unless there's an option that I have unchecked somewhere that I don't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you view the waveforms, you can right click on the trace, and click "Trace Information". This will show the parameter value used corresponding to that trace.

***EDIT***

Double sweeps:

To be honest im not sure how to read the sweep value then, but if you use "parametric sweep" instead, you can do as i described above. So you use "primary" and "parametric" sweep.

Comment: See edit to question; I'm pasting a screenshot.

Comment: @JohnDoe: Okay yea i see what you are doing. You are using the secondary sweep also. To be honest im not sure how to read the sweep value then, but if you use "parametric sweep" instead, you can do as i described above. So you use "primary" and "parametric" sweep.

Comment: Thank you! That has been incredibly frustrating in the past. You're the best!

Comment: @JohnDoe: No problem. This is a rather old question, i thought you had figured something out in the meantime :)

Comment: Nope! My job is not in IC design, but my schooling is. I try to keep up as much as I can, which is not very much.